# Implementing a separate process in an activity diagram

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I was wondering, how do you implement a different process in an activity diagram? For example, I have following diagram:

[image]

Now, if I want to show in the diagram that the system should backup all files on my computer every 10 pm, how would I do this?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Accept Time Event Action as depicted below.

[image]

Comment: I have added a new diagram, would this suffice and be understandable for others?

Answer (score 0):

Use a decision symbol to state two separate works, and the hour glass for waiting.

[image]